# Where to keep test-supplementary classes?

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven-2

I'm trying to create this directory structure in Maven Java project:

```
pom.xml
/src
  /main
    /java
      /com
        /XXX
          Foo.java
          Bar.java
  /test
    /java
      /com
        /XXX
          FooTest.java
          BarTest.java
    /spikes <---- I'm not sure about the right English word for them
      /com
        /XXX
          MockedHttpConnection.java
```

Thus, in two tests `FooTest` and `BarTest` I can use the same `MockedHttpConnection`, which is perfectly decoupled from them both, staying at the same time in the same package with them. What do you think about this approach? I have a feeling that I'm reinventing a wheel, but I can't find any patterns for this mechanism in Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If MockedHttpConnection is your own class I'd suggest you to store it under `/test/java/com/testutil`.

If it is third party class, just add jar to your `classpath`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd sugget having it in your test package because in the end is testing code.

It's the same as the application. You don't just store your application main class under main. You store it and everything it needs to be executed.